# terraform file provisioner looks like it succeeds but doesn't copy file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm learning how to use terraform to provision aws resources. In my current test project amongst other things I'm creating an ec2 instance and trying to use a file provisioner to copy some files up to the server.

My instance configuration looks like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "minecraft_ec2" {
  instance_type = "c6g.large"
  ami           = data.aws_ami.server_ami.id

  key_name        = aws_key_pair.minecraft_auth.key_name
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.minecraft_security_group.id]
  subnet_id       = aws_subnet.minecraft_subnet.id

  user_data = file("userdata.tpl")

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "./scripts"
    destination = "~/"

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "ec2-user"
      private_key = file("~/.ssh/minecraft_key")
      host        = self.public_ip
      timeout     = "1m"
    }
  }
```

Where `./scripts` is a set of python files in my infrastructure directory (same directory as my tf files) that has some logic I want to run on the instance after it's created.

[image: scripts directory relative to tf files]

And the ssh private key that I'm providing is the same one I'm using as the key for my aws_instance:

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "minecraft_auth" {
  key_name   = "minecraft_key"
  public_key = file("~/.ssh/minecraft_key.pub")
}
```

When I run my my terraform apply to create or replace the aws instance the file provisioning seems to run without error (I've forced it to error by giving it a super short timeout and the output definitely shows differently when it fails):

[image: provisioning seems to run fine]

but when I ssh into the instance to see how things went the scripts directory has not been scp-ed up:

[image: no scripts folder in user home folder on instance]

I'm guessing there's some failure that's being swallowed or suppressed, but I'm not sure how to see it or what could be failing. I can ssh into the instance using the same private key, so it seems like the connection shouldn't be an issue, but yeah I'm not sure where things are going wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there maybe a `scripts` directory anywhere else on the file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
provisioner "file" {
    source      = "./scripts"
    destination = "~/"
```

try:

```
provisioner "file" {
    source      = "${path.module}/scripts"
    destination = "/home/ec2-user/"
```

I would also check your root home directory for `scripts` just in case since it is weird that terraform provisioned successfully yet you can't find it.

And last but not least check any provisioning logs on the server once it's up and running.

Comment: this worked for me, though I didn't need the `file` helper function. using the `path.module` tool to get the relative directory and being absolute about the destination did the trick :) thanks for the help!